# Click handler inside another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a structure that uses a couple of list elements that hold anchor tags.  Basically, I have a click handler on the list element itself, and another click handler on the anchor tag within it.  However, the issue I am having is that when I click on the anchor tag, it fires the list element's click handler.

```js
$(".myStructure").on("click", ".myLis", doSomeAction);
$(".myStructure").on("click", "#myLink2", doSomeAction2);
```

```html
<div class="myStructure">
  <li class="myLis">
    <a id="myLink">ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="myLis">
    <a id="myLink2">ABC</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do so that when I click on the anchor tag it invokes the method that I want it to?  I can't seem to find out what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) from link event handler.

[event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
function doSomeAction2(event)
{
    //your code
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myStructure">
      <li class="myLis">
        <a id="myLink" href="#">ABC</a>
      </li>
      <li class="myLis">
        <a id="myLink2" href="#">ABC</a>
      </li>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myLink").on("click", function(){
        console.log('hi')
    });
    $("#myLink2").on("click", function(){
        console.log('ho')
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a wonderful solution to this. You can just bind the element event listener to the root node and listen it's events using event bubbling

```
$(".myStructure").each( function() {
    // Binds the event only once to the root element
    this.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

       // The critical point is here!!!
       var elem = $(event.target);

       // and after you have the element, it is easy to check which it was
       if(elem.hasClass("myLis")) {
          alert("List element click!");
       }
       if(elem.prop("tagName")=="A") {
          alert("A element was clicked!");
       }                          
    });
});
```

You can use this pattern to do much more complex things and have only one event handler dispatching the actions to correct functions.

Testbench is here http://jsfiddle.net/Lh5omcdn/

**EDIT**: The difficulty with this solution is that you have to check from the event target what you should do. If the target does not have attribute, class or some other meta -information, then you don't know what to do. The advantage of having only one event -handler has it's costs.

However, this disadvantage can turn out to be a benefit in case you are using some sort of templating engine, which generates the HTML. Then you do not have to re-bind the events to the HTML contents each time you re-assign new HTML to the "myStructure" -element.